Convergence of a second order non-linear recurrence
While attempting to solve a probability problem, I was led to set up the following recurrence
$$x_{n+1} = 1 - \dfrac{2}{3}x_n - \dfrac{2}{3}x_{n-1} + \dfrac{2}{3}x_nx_{n-1}, \text{with} \hspace{3mm} x_1 = x_2 = \frac{1}{3}.$$
By numerical computations, it seems as if the limit of the sequence $(x_n)$ is $\dfrac{1}{2}$. Indeed, if we assume convergence, we have
$\lambda = 1 - \dfrac{2}{3}\lambda - \dfrac{2}{3}\lambda + \dfrac{2}{3} \lambda^2 \implies \lambda = 3$ or $\lambda = \dfrac{1}{2}$, where we reject the former solution since $0 \leq x_n \leq 1$ in our context. Interestingly, any choice of initial values $x_1 = x_2 \in [0,1]$ yields the same result.
However, proving convergence eludes me. One line of thought I had was to show that $(x_n)$ is bounded (easy) and Cauchy (not obvious why).
I have also tried manipulating the recurrence into equivalent forms such as
$$v(n+1) = \dfrac{2}{3}v(n)v(n-1) - \dfrac{1}{3} \left[v(n) + v(n-1) \right], \hspace{2mm} v(1)=v(2)=-\dfrac{1}{6},$$
or
$$u(n+1) = \dfrac{2}{3}u(n)u(n-1) - \dfrac{2}{3}, \hspace{2mm} u(1)=u(2)=-\dfrac{2}{3},$$
but I am not sure how to proceed.

Try $x_n = \dfrac{1}{2} + y_n$. Everything magically cancels, and you end up with $y_{n+1} = \dfrac{2}{3}y_n y_{n-1}$.

After, the recurrence can be recast as $l_{n+1}=l_n+l_{n-1}+c$

last let $y_n = e^{z_n}$  so $z_n = \log y_n$

Take $\frac{1}{2}$ as the guess for the limit. Define the new sequence
$$a_n=x_n-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$a_n+\frac{1}{2}=x_n$$
Then the recurrence becomes
$$x_{n+1} = 1 - \dfrac{2}{3}x_n - \dfrac{2}{3}x_{n-1} + \dfrac{2}{3}x_nx_{n-1}, \text{with} \hspace{3mm} x_1 = x_2 = \frac{1}{3}$$
$$3a_{n+1}=2a_na_{n-1}-a_n-a_{n-1}, \text{with} \hspace{3mm} a_1 = a_2 = -\frac{1}{6}$$
We will now prove by induction that $|a_n|<3^{-\frac{n}{10}}$. This can be manually checked for small $n\leq 15$. Assume that $|a_n|<3^{-\frac{n}{10}}$. The algebra is a little tedious, but we can show that
$$|a_{n+1}|\leq 3^{-\frac{n+1}{10}}\left(2\cdot 3^{-\frac{n+8}{10}}+3^{-\frac{9}{10}}+3^{-\frac{4}{5}}\right)$$
For $n\geq 13$ we have
$$2\cdot 3^{-\frac{n+8}{10}}+3^{-\frac{9}{10}}+3^{-\frac{4}{5}}\leq 2\cdot 3^{-\frac{13+8}{10}}+3^{-\frac{9}{10}}+3^{-\frac{4}{5}}<.99<1$$
so we may conclude that
$$|a_{n+1}|<3^{-\frac{n+1}{10}}\to 0$$
Thus, $|a_n|=\left|x_n-\frac{1}{2}\right|$ goes to $0$ and we are done.
